# Is "shutdown -r now" safe?

Tags: boot, reboot

Is it safe to reboot your VPS this way, or does it kill all processes directly?

And if not, what is the right way?

Comment: Why do you feel there is a problem with this?

Comment: @mdpc Im just wondering if its a safe shutdown or a hard kill?

Comment: I have barley used a VPS before but under the FAQ it specially states you can use this method or use the admin panel to do a controlled shutdown.  Does your VPS service not have an FAQ or wiki of some sort?